# Why are concretizable categories locally small?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I have seen it mentioned in a few places that concrete (or concretizable) categories are locally small, but never seen any proof.
Is it particularly trivial? If not, does anybody have some reference or sketch proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, the concrete $\mathcal C$ has a faithful functor $U: \mathcal C \to \text{Set}$. In other words, for any pair of objects $c, d \in \mathcal C$ the assignment $Hom (c, d) \to Hom(Uc, Ud)$ via $U$ is injective. Since the latter is a set, the former must be a set too.